# Facebook SDK: Comments box storage and Android integration

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook Comments Box API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Questions:

1. The users' comments will be stored on Facebook server. We don't have
   to worry about managing them in our database, unless we want to
   store them in our db. Is this correct?
2. I'm working on an app that lets users share and comment on photos. Is there FB Comments API for Android app (natively or via webview)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584176/failed-to-render-facebook-comments-on-android-webview-via-local-html#autocomment31184887

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108610/facebook-comment-box-in-android