# Facebook comment box in Android

Tags: android, facebook

In my app, I would like to show comments in my website by webview.
This is what I have done:

In assets folder I have got a file named **comment.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=467390796664437";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.haivl.com/photo/1259735" data-width="470"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

- In **CommentViewActivity.java**

  ```
  public class CommentViewActivity extends Activity {
  public static Context context;
  private WebView webView;

  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_zini_login);
      context = this;
      CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
      CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
      cm.removeAllCookie();
      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_login);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/comment.html");
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientActivity());
  }

  public class WebViewClientActivity extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
          System.out.println("onPageStarted: " + url);

        }

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
          System.out.println("onPageFinished: " + url);

        }
  }
  }
  ```

The activity displays as follow:
[image]

As you can see, the facebook comment box obscured and I can't see whole comments.
Anyone has a idea?

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

base on this post [Failed to render Facebook comments on Android WebView via local HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584176/failed-to-render-facebook-comments-on-android-webview-via-local-html#autocomment31184887)?

You need to specify a base URL.

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.haivl.com", 
"<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=467390796664437";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.haivl.com/photo/1259735" data-width="470"></div> 
</body>
</html>", "text/html", null, null);
```